# Is there any pragmatic implication in ‘Beaky has enjoyed London’ here?

Tags: grammar, connotation, present-perfect

It says on a grammar book that in some cases, the present perfect form has pragmatic meanings.

> Joan has broken the teapot. (I have to get a new one.)
>
> I’ve had a bath. (I’m now clean.)

Is there such implication in the following “Beaky has enjoyed London.”? Or is Hagrid merely reporting the fact?

(A letter from Hagrid (in London) to Hermione (at Hogwarts) just after losing a case)

> Dear Hermione,
>
> We lost. I’m allowed to bring him back to Hogwarts.
>
> Execution date to be fixed.
>
> Beaky has enjoyed London.
>
> I won’t forget all the help you gave us.
>
> Hagrid. (*Harry Potter 3* [US Version]: p.291)

**N.B.:** Beaky is Hagrid’s pet, a treasure to Hagrid, which was judged dangerous and received a death sentence. In the book, there’re several teardrops smudging the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any pragmatic implication? Well, I wouldn't say so. Why? Because, if there were pragmatic implications, what would one do as a result of knowing that Beaky enjoyed London? Would we eat dinner? Would we sing and be happy?

Obviously not. This sentence, is different from the previous examples that you gave, in which there is an implication for another action to be performed (or that has been performed), for example "Joan has broken the teapot" implies that a replacement needs to be found. However, this is not the case with "Beaky has enjoyed London".

It's like making a statement "I have enjoyed my meal". No necessary action needs to take place after this statement (Unless, to burp)

Answer (score 2):

The implication is just that what happens when someone enjoys something.

You would need some insight in how Beaky would react to enjoying a city, but there would probably just be an improvement in the mood:

> Beaky has enjoyed London. (Beaky is now happy.)

There is of course also a deeper meaning that you can draw from the fact that Hagrid is mentioning Beaky at all, which would indicate the importance of Beaky to Hagrid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there can be any pragmatic meaning. There is no direct result of Beaky liking the city of London (like being clean after taking a bath or being in need to buy new cup after someone broke the old one). Hagrid is simply stating the fact, nothing more, nothing less.